# Magento :: Layout in Module

Tags: layout, magento, module, block

Is it possible to create a layout file inside of a module ? How ?

For what:
I want to add a some kind of statistics hit counter for products, and I don't want to override the products class, as that is already done by some module I'm using. Thus I thought it would be best to have a custom module with a block that would be called by a layout statement.
Of course I could easily edit my private local.xml or make changes to another layout-xml in the layout folder of my theme, but I want this feature to be available in all themes (independent of any selected theme).

Some constraints:

- All code in one single module
- ... so that it is theme independent
- ... so that the module can be shared with others without them having to change anything (like theme files), so that the install/load of my module would be enough

I would also accept different approaches for my statistics hit counter loading (using the same constraints)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just create your layout xml file in the following path: /design/frontend/default/default/layout/yourlayout.xml(or whatever your theme name is), and add a proper statement in your modules etc/config.xml:

```
<config> 
 <frontend>   
  <layout>
    <updates>
      <yourmoduleshortname>
         <file>yourlayout.xml</file>
      <yourmoduleshortname>
    </updates>
  </layout>  
 </frontend>
</config>
```

This sample is for frontend user, but adminhtml layouts can be updated in a similar manner. If something doesn't work, be sure to check if your layout is in the proper theme/package directory.

**Edit:**

*Second approach:*

You can use a controller of your own, which will extend the core functionality (one of the catalog controllers) - just rewrite it (or just product view action). Inside its action method add something like this:

```
$thiss->getLayout()->createBlock('namespacename/block','layout-block-name',
array('template' => 'relativepathtotemplate.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
run-original-parent-code();
```

*Third approach:*

Similar to the previous one, but you can use some event observer, and try `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')`, and inject your block there. Not in all events the layout will be already available (try the post_dispatch family).

I don't really recommend the second and third approach, because if someone else wants to find where this 'magic' block comes from, it will most surely look int app/design/(...) directory. Finding it in your controller or model, may be very tricky...

If you don't want to display your statistic counter, you can also use events (like post_dispatch) to count the controller dispatches. Just create an observer attached to it, and store your data in the DB.

Comment: and is that theme you're talking about independent of the theme another developer (having installed my module) might select for the store/page/category etc...

Comment: In Magento 1.x you can't store a layout file inside your module's directory (this is going to be implemented in Magento 2 - all module files in one dir). Its a pretty common thing to have a module scattered over code, desing, etc, skin a js dirs, so don't worry about that. Although there is another option... I updated my answer with a diffrent approach.

Comment: I think the events way is the best approach because indeed I don't need to output anything while counting (also I don't want to override any classes !). So events sounds nice. I only thought of blocks and layouts, because by I adding my block to the product.info block, my block (the important logic) would have been called each time the product page would be opened. Now that you told me about events I think they are the better way.

Comment: My event observer gets called now (on catalog_controller_product_view). Now I fail to get the product object being called/displayed. From within a block this would have worked: $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info')->getProduct()->getName();
Now of course I'm not in a block context and getLayout() isn't available. Do you know of a way to get the current viewed product with a different technique from within the observer method.

Comment: I see that Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info') also doesn't work. So I guess that the event is thrown before the product.info block has been generated

Comment: Ah I found the solution: $observer->getEvent->getProduct(); http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method thx for your help :D

Comment: If you have such a problem, you can grep the code/core directory for the event you are looking for. You will find something like this: Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_controller_product_view', array('product' => $product)); The last part is the arguments of the observer. As you know, for this particulart event, you can call getProduct :)